# How to trigger a custom function on sign-in click in the Authenticator component of aws-amplify/ui-react?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using the Authenticator component from @aws-amplify/ui-react and I need to trigger a custom function with the click of the sign-in button. For example, when it is clicked it will trigger a custom function that sends a custom event to Google Analytics 4.
Is it possible? Docs didn't help me much.
This is my code so far:

```
const components: any = {
    Header() {
        return (
            <View className="icon-view" textAlign="center">
                <Icon name="test-light" />
            </View>
        );
    },
    Footer() {
        return (
            <View className="footer" textAlign="center">
                <Text>
                    <strong>Footer here</strong>
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    },
};

const formFields = {
    signIn: {
        username: {
            label: '',
        },
        password: { label: '' },
    },
    resetPassword: {
        username: {
            label: '',
        },
    },
    confirmResetPassword: {
        confirmation_code: {
            label: '',
        },
        password: {
            label: '',
        },
        confirm_password: {
            label: '',
        },
    },
};
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Authenticator
      hideSignUp={true}
      formFields={formFields}
      components={components}
    >
      {({ user, signOut }) => {
        const value: any = {
          user,
          signOut,
          userRole: user?.attributes?.['custom:role'] as ROLE,
        };

        return (
          <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
        );
      }}
    </Authenticator>
  );
};
```